# What variables go into the StatefulWidget class and which go into the State class

Tags: flutter, dart

Which variables should be placed in State and which should be included in the StatefulWidget when creating a stateful widget?

Comment: What do you mean by "state class"? Are you asking the difference between statefulwidget and statelesswidget?

Comment: When creating a `StatefulWidget`, you need to also create a class that extends the `State` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables declared inside the class extending **StatefulWidget** can only be of the type **final** so they cannot be changed. These variables can be accessed with the following syntax **widget.<variable name>**.

Variables declared inside the class extending **State** can be of any type and these variables can be changed through setState or by just assigning a new value to it.